# javascript/jquery recover value of arraylist object attibute

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc, arraylist

I'm afraid my title is somewhat messy. 
I am working with Spring MVC and my form is associated to a class with several ArrayList and when trying to get javascript(jquery is fine) to recover the value of one o its attributes it always returns "undefined" of [Object object] instead of the value.

My jsp

```
        <c:forEach var="item" items="${form.fact}" varStatus="status">
                   <tr>
                        <td>
                            <sf:hidden path="fact[${status.index}].name"/>
                            <c:out value="${form.fact[status.index].name}" />
                        </td>
                        <sf:hidden path="fact[${status.index}].id"/>
                    </tr>
         </c:forEach>
```

The value I'm trying to recover for my js is the one that is hidden, that is, the "id".

when using:

```
var nm= $("fact2.id").val();
```

I get undefined although when checking the code of the page I see:

```
 <input id="fact2.id" name="fact[2].id" type="hidden" value="55572"/>
```

I have tried with

```
document.getElementById("fact2.id")
document.getElementsByName("fact[2].id")
```

but can't manage to get the value.

If anybody can help I would greatly appreciate it. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is wrong, you need to use [id-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) (#id) also need to escape the `.` in the id

```
var nm= $("#fact2\\.id").val();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The id-selector was a tipyng error, it was there originally, but I hadn't thought about escaping the <code>.</code>. Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check  This. It is working fine.This is working in all cases. In case of any issue please let me know.

$("[id^=fact2]").val();